# How to pass variable back and forth between page through bottomnavigationbar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to sending variable from one page to second page through BottomNavigationBar switching page and send variable at same time. but I don't know how to send variable through switching page.

Answer (score 0):

In your `FirstRoute` You can do it in the constructor of the class you're navigating to. In this case we want to Navigate to the `SecondRoute`. So let's say we have an `onPressed` function in a Button in the first screen. With that we will navigate. Pay attention, because we created a variable called `myNumber` that will save a value in the future. You'll see later. But first let's pass some `String` to the second Route through its constructor:

```
onPressed: () async {
   var myNumber = await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute("I want to pass this String")),
  );
}
```

In your `SecondRoute` you should have the constructor to give it the value you want to hold. This `String value` will now have the "I want to pass this String" value. The class with the constructor is as following:

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {

  SecondRoute(this.value);
  final String value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, 5); //Here you pass a value. Say a number.                                                 
                                       //Like five.
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And then, if you read with attention the code, you saw the comment where I indicate how can you then pass a value when popping that screen. In this case I just passed a number five, but you could pass whatever you want. In that way, when you pop that screen, you will get the value. Where? It'll be saved in the previously created variable `myNumber` in the first screen when we did the navigation. And remember, since it is a value that comes in the future, you should use `async` and `await`.

Answer (score 0):

I add sample code for you and it possible to do with this example code pass first page to other? like when click business or school page changing and send variable too.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  String text_val = "";
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  TextStyle optionStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text("Index 0:Home"),
        Container(
          width: 300,
          child: TextField(
             onChanged: (text) {
                print("First text field: $text");
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Enter text",
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    Container(
      child: Text("Index 1:Home"),
    ),
    Container(
      child: Text("Index 2:Home"),
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```